# is it possible to convert Mechanize::File into Mechanize::Page

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I'm having a trouble with Mechanize gem, how to convert **Mechanize::File** into **Mechanize::Page**,

here's my piece of code:

```
**link** = page.link_with(:href => %r{/en/users}).click
```

when users link clicked it goes to the page with the list of users, now i want to click the first user, but i can't achieve this, because **link** return **Mechanize::File** object

Any help, suggestions 'd be great, thanks

Comment: are there anyone who knows how to handle such situations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mechanize uses Content-Type to determine how the resource should be handled. Occasionally websites will not set the mime-types for their resources. `Mechanize::File` is the default for unset Content-Type.

If you are only dealing with `'text/html'` you can following Jimm Stout's [suggestion](http://jimmstout.com/2012/adding-a-default-content-type-to-mechanize-agent/) of using `post_connect_hooks`

```
agent = Mechanize.new do |a|
  a.post_connect_hooks << ->(_,_,response,_) do
    if response.content_type.empty?
      response.content_type = 'text/html'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the body with nokogiri:

```
link = page.link_with(:href => %r{/en/users}).click
doc = Nokogiri::HTML link.body
agent.get doc.at('a')[:href]
```